# How to append date and time in multiple file in a folder while moving it to another folder

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
```

Source Folder

```
     File source = new File("D:\\A1\\"); 
     File dest = new File("D:\\A2\\");
     File[] files = source.listFiles(); 


    for (File file: source.listFiles()){
               String x=(source+"\\"+file.getName());
         String y=(dest + "\\"+ file.getName());

     File f1 = new File(x);
     f1.renameTo(new File(y));      

     }
```

This code is moving the file from source to destination folder but i want when file moved to destination folder . it appends the the system date with its name 
Please Help

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do two things at the same time. Keep it simple (KISS), do one thing at a time. If you are not allowed to rename it in the source folder, first copy it to a temp-directory, change name, then copy the results to the output. You shouldn't worry too much about performance until you can prove that it is a problem.

Comment: You are on right track just insert formatted system date in this statement `String y=(dest + "\\"+ file.getName());`

Comment: @Sanjeev i tried it like String y=(dest + ("\\"+ file.getName()+" "+date)); but when i do it like that it dont copy to dest folder

Comment: @Anandv any exceptions in copy process?

Comment: @Sanjeev no exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the timestamp to the filename, at best right before the extension.

Note that operating systems may not allow some characters to appear in a filename, for example the colon and the slash may not be use on windows, so yo need to find a substitue for them.

Also you need to check the return value of [renameTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo-java.io.File-) to check whether the file was realy moved or not.

> returns true if and only if the renaming succeeded; false otherwise

You could try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    String ts = dateFormat.format(date);

    File source = new File("D:\\A1\\");
    File dest = new File("D:\\A2\\");

    for (File file : source.listFiles()) {
        String x = (source + "\\" + file.getName());
        String y = (dest + "\\" + addTimestamp(file.getName(), ts));

        File f1 = new File(x);
        if(f1.renameTo(new File(y))){
            System.out.println("moved: " + y);
        } else {
            System.out.println("unable to move: " + y);
        }
    }
}

private static String addTimestamp(String name, String ts) {
    int lastIndexOf = name.lastIndexOf('.');
    return (lastIndexOf == -1 ? 
            name + "_" + ts 
            : 
            name.substring(0, lastIndexOf) + "_" + ts + 
            name.substring(lastIndexOf))
             .replaceAll("[\\/:\\*\\?\"<>| ]", "_");
}
```

Finally for moving files better use [Files#move](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) as the javadoc of `renameTo` itself suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
Date date = new Date();
y=(dest + "\\"+ file.getName()+dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: i tried your code , it print with the date and time but doesn't copy to destination folder

Comment: You may try using the `move` method instead of `renameTo`

Answer (score 0):

As per Java Docs of File#renameTo method, it is a platform dependent implementation and it may not work as you expect.

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>   platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a
>   file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it
>   might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
>   already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure
>   that the rename operation was successful.
>
> Note that the Files class defines the move method to move or rename a
>   file in a platform independent manner.

You can alternatively use [Files#move](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) method. It is a Platform Independent method.

Hope this helps